# How to clear UI Thread queue

Tags: android

I use `runOnUIThread` method to pass `Runnable` tasks to the main thread queue, but I need to clear all queue tasks, that I sent before, before sending a new one. How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use an `Handler` to post. It has the same effect of runOnUiThread. On your handler instance you can call `removeCallbacks(null)`, which will remove every element in the Handler queue, or  `removeCallbacks(yourannableinstance)` which remove every element of `yourannableinstance` kind

Comment: Agree with the above answer. Using Handler is a better option. Adding to the answer check the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html and to remove http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `removeCallbacks(Runnable r)` method. If they are anonymous then you can use `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`. If this doesn't fix the problem please give me more details

Answer (score 1):

The UI thread is also a `Looper` thread, and it **only have one** `Message Queue`.

So if you create a handler in UI thread, and then call `handler.post(runnable)`, the runnable task will store **in the message queue**.

If you call `runOnUIThread()`, the run task will also **store in the same message queue**.

```
5289    public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
5290        if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
5291            mHandler.post(action); // runOnUiThread also calls handler.post()
5292        } else {
5293            action.run();
5294        }
5295    }
```

And `mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` would help you to remove all callbacks and messages.

Comment: From what I observed, difference handler variable with same ThreadHandler looper not able  `.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` to cancel each other, instead must use the same handler reference. Even two `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` not able cancel each other.